# GCP: Network load balancer changes HTTP version from 1.1 to 1.0

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

I'm using two type of load balancers: HTTP LB for front-end and Network load balancer as an internal LB. I noticed GCP's Network load balancer (L4 load balancer) changes HTTP version from 1.1 to 1.0. Is this my understanding correct? How to change the Network LB's behavior. I don't think changing the version is good.

My Environment

```
User --> HTTP LB  --> Server A --> Network LB  --> Server B
```

Server A's log

```
1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/May/2017:15:04:41 +0900] "GET /items HTTP/1.1" 200 260 "-" "-"
```

Server B's log

```
1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [15/May/2017:15:04:41 +0900] "GET /items HTTP/1.0" 200 260 "-" "-"
```

---

Update 1

It might  be not GCP LB's behavior. I doubted nginx proxy setting.

I put the following setting into nginx conf. But still it does not work.

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The cause was our nginx setting. 
We use nginx proxy. The proxy's default setting is HTTP 1.1.
We put the following line. Then fixed it.

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```